# Select all include blank and Null values in the multiple-selection

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I have several filters in the SSRS report.
I would like to use multiple-selection but I have blank values.
What can I do when I want to choose Select all and in this case I want to include all values (Blank and Null)?

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the Blank and Null values with a dummy value e.g. 'Unspecified' (assuming it's a text column.

Ideally, that happens upstream from SSRS for best performance and consistent results. If necessary you might have to derive that as a column in your dataset SQL, or even a dataset calculated column with an SSRS expression as a last resort.

Note your dataset driving the parameter must stay consistent with the dataset(s) providing the report page data.